# Enumerations in Russian - is an "и" needed?

Tags: грамматика, пунктуация, conjunctions

When listing things in Russian using commas, do you use an "и" before the last thing, e.g. "столы, стулья и полки", or should it just be "столы, стулья, полки"?

I've seen some internet pages omitting the "и", but it's not explained anywhere, so I don't know why.

Answer (score 9):

Both

> столы, стулья, полки

and

> столы, стулья и полки

are appropriate. The conjunction "и" (in Russian - "союз") before the last element marks it as the last element and logically completes the sentence.

Another option is logical pairing/binding, for example:

> столы и стулья, полки и шкафы, серванты и лавки

This could be used to logically group item pairs, or to subscribe a long enumeration (lots of elements).

Comment: Additionally... In the second case, one can write in English _"desks, chairs, and shelves"_ using comma before _"and"_. However, in Russian comma and conjunction _"и"_ are mutually exclusive.  One uses either comma, or _"и",_ but never both at the same time.

Comment: @Vitaly *"и столы, и стулья"*

Answer (score 4):

It's up to you to decide whether to use и or not. In colloquial  speech, the rules aren't strict. But in written speech — especially in scientific works — they do exist.

If the last word in enumeration is added without the conjunction **и**, the chain is meant and perceived as unfinished and open for possible addition (in some cases, the phrases *и так далее*, *и тому подобное*, *и прочее* can be used).
An example from a scientific text:

> Инфекции могут подразделяться на антропонозы (полиомиелит, менинго- кокковая инфекция, вирусный гепатит и др.) и зоонозы (бешенство, бруцеллез, лептоспироз, туляремия и пр.).

Enumeration is considered finished when the last word is linked with the conjunction *и*. The conjunction shows that the list is complete, exhaustive, and doesn't require additional information.

> Музыкальные звуки различаются по силе, высоте и тембру.

Answer (score 3):

The last `и` isn't required, but its usage is pretty natural in the most cases.

Answer (score 3):

There's another one type of enumeration (not listed in previous answers). It's used when you want to emphasize that all items in the list have a certain property:

> В этой комнате и столы, и стулья, и полки, и шкафы были выкрашены в белый цвет.

Here, you put the conjunction `и` before each word and a comma between the words in the list.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the other answers, it's worth pointing out that when the conjunction *и* is used, the implied meaning is that the list is complete, i.e. you've listed everything that's relevant:

> Столы, стулья и полки [and nothing else]

When the conjunction is omitted, the implied meaning is that there may be other relevant items, but you don't really want/need to list them all, so you've only listed a few:

> Столы, стулья, полки [and maybe other items of furniture]